# extracting from a tar file with duplicate entry names

Tags: bash, tar

If you add the same file to a tar file multiple times, and then extract that file, are you guaranteed that the extracted version is equivalent to the one which was last added?

```
~/tmp> echo hi > foo
~/tmp> tar -cf bar.tar foo
~/tmp> echo bye > foo
~/tmp> tar -uf bar.tar foo 
~/tmp> tar -tf bar.tar
foo
foo
~/tmp> rm foo
~/tmp> tar -xf bar.tar foo
~/tmp> cat foo
bye
```

It make sense that it would, but I can't find any documentation to that effect.   I'm wondering if anyone in the know might know, or if someone knows a circumstance where this is not true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Some documentation for tar](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/tar_4.html) says this:

> When you extract a file from the archive, only the version stored last
> will wind up in the file system. Because '--extract' ('-x') extracts
> files from an archive in sequence, and overwrites files with the same
> name in the file system, if a file name appears more than once in an
> archive the last version of the file will overwrite the previous
> versions which have just been extracted. You should avoid storing
> older versions of a file later in the archive.

My understanding is that, unless you use the `--keep-old-files` option, `-x` will always overwrite with the last file stored in the archive.

Edit: see also the [GNU documentation for `tar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC61).

Comment: See also `--occurrence` in the [tar Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC42) section of the manual.